# Best way to upload images to another server in php

Tags: php, file-upload, cross-domain

I need to upload an image to another server once it's been submitted by a user. I have 3 ways to accomplish it.

1. Upload the image to the primary server and then upload it to another server via ftp.
2. Upload the image to the primary server and store it somewhere in the temp folder. Then, run a cron script to upload images from the temp folder to another server.
3. Have a php script which would accept images uploaded directly to another server.

Please note, I need to store image references and some metadata in the primary server database. So, by keeping that in mind makes me automatically drop the 3rd choice from the list. Since, it's hard to get the uploaded image file name from another server once it's there.

The first one, is a good one since I can generate the file name before I upload it to another server and once it's there I can easily save the required data into the database. The obvious drawback here is that this requires extra patience for the user while the image is being uploaded first to the primary server, then to another server.

The second method seems the best one for me, since the image will be uploaded to another server unnoticeable for users. The only thing bothers me is that the url for the uploaded image will be changed once the cron uploads the image to another server. Not sure what side effects might come up later because of this.

Has anybody done something similar before? If yes, please share your experience with me.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In your best case, what command will cron run ? I mean FTP ?

Comment: Yes, the cron will upload all images from the primary server to the second server via ftp, and then, will update the links of the images in the database. The transferred images will be deleted in the primary server after.

Comment: Well, I haven't tried but I think running cron is fine. 

You can display the new url only when the file exist on the new server. So i don't think you should face any issues.

Comment: I ended up uploading files to the primary server first, and then to another server by cron via CURL. I prefer curl over ftp due to the fact that it gives the opportunity to retrieve some custom response from another server once the file is uploaded.